# Get the Type from a Grid using a custom datasource which inherits BindingList<T> and implements IBindingListView using C# and .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, types, bindinglist

I have a custom sortable list which inherits BindingList and implements IBindingListView:

```
public class MySortableView<T> : BindingList<T>, IBindingListView
{
    ...
}
```

I use this custom list as my datasource on a grid:

```
gridCustomers.DataSource = new MySortableView<Customer>(listCustomers);
```

My problem comes when I remove a row from the grid. Before a row is deleted I copy the contents of the grid into a list of objects using a for loop iterating through the grid rows. The row is then removed from this list of objects and I then set the DataSource of the grid again to be the list of objects.

```
//Before delete:
listObjects = new List<object>();

for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < gridCustomers.Rows.Count; iIndex++)
{
    listObjects.Add(gridCustomers.Rows[iIndex].DataItem);
}

//After delete I set the datasource to listObjects
gridCustomers.DataSource = listObjects
```

This runs, however after doing this I am no longer able to sort the contents of my grid because the grid is no longer using MySortableView.

So I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
Type listObjectsType;

//Get the type before removing the row
listObjectsType = gridCustomers.Rows[iIndex].DataItem.GetType();

//Set datasource back using the stored type.
gridCustomers.DataSource = new MySortableView<listObjectType>(listObjects);
```

When I try the above I receive the following error:

listObjectType is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

This may seem a silly way of doing this but the type Customer exists in a different assembly.

Help please!!

I hope this all makes sense.

I'm using C#, .Net 4.0 and the entity framework.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a DataGridView ?

Comment: No, it's a 3rd party grid but it's not too different.

Comment: Right, and what is this "DataItem"? Is it a collection or an object?

Comment: It's an object but I think it'll be set to the type set in the DataSource. So in case Customer

Answer (score 0):

Will you always have a Customer Type in your DataGrid or others too?
Maybe you can try something like this:

```
Type listObjectsType = typeof(Customer);
```

Comment: It could be others too. listObjectsType is in a different assembly so wouldn't know what Customer is which is why I'm tying to get the type out of the DataItem

Comment: Hum, ok. And what if you get the type directly from your list? Can you do that? Like Type listObjectsType = listObjects.GetType(); or listCustomer.GetType(); ? Because I tested here, and the default DataGridView works. I'm getting the Type exactly like you, but with DataBoundItem (dgtTest.Rows[intIndex].DataBoundItem.GetType()).

Comment: No I can't as listObjects is of type object and listCustomers a list of customers but Customer is not known in that assembly. My grid in part of a user control that is used in different applications.